# Trying to train a model to generate text on my GPU, and keep getting [UNK] and "NaN" loss on one computer. However, on my MacBook it works just fine

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the full code. This currently works just fine on my M1 MacBook running Monterey and Tensorflow-Metal. However, when I export the dataset and code to my laptop with an RTX 3060 Laptop GPU with Pop_OS! that is when I start getting the [UNK] characters generated and "NaN" loss. I'm unsure of what steps to take to make this better. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import os, sys, time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import StringLookup
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

BATCH_SIZE = 128
BUFFER_SIZE = 10_000

EMBEDDING_DIMENSION = 128
RNN_UNITS = 1024 

CHECKPOINT_DIR = './training_checkpoints'
CHECKPOINT_PREFIX = os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, "ckpt_{epoch}")

EPOCHS = 16

def text_from_ids(ids):
  return tf.strings.reduce_join(chars_from_ids(ids), axis=1)

def split_input_target(sequence):
  input_text = sequence[:-1]
  target_text = sequence[1:]
  return input_text, target_text

def generate_text(model, seed_text, next_words, max_sequence_len):
    for _ in range(next_words):
        token_list = Tokenizer().texts_to_sequences([seed_text])[0]
        token_list = pad_sequences([token_list], maxlen=max_sequence_len-1, padding='pre')
        predicted = model.predict(token_list, verbose=0)
        
        output_word = ""
        for word,index in Tokenizer().word_index.items():
            if index == predicted:
                output_word = word
                break
        seed_text += " "+output_word
    return seed_text.title()

def generate_char(inputs):
  input_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(ids_from_chars(inputs))

  predicted_logits = model(inputs=np.array([input_ids]))
  predicted_logits = predicted_logits[:, -1, :]
  # print(predicted_logits)
  predicted_logits = predicted_logits/1.0
  # print(predicted_logits)

  predicted_ids = tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)
  predicted_ids = tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)

  return chars_from_ids(predicted_ids)

text = open("./data.txt", "rb").read().decode(encoding="UTF-8")
vocab = sorted(set(text))
vocab_size = len(vocab)

print(f"Text Length: {len(text)}")
print(f"Text Vocab: {vocab}")
print(f"Text Vocab Size: {vocab_size}")

ids_from_chars = StringLookup(vocabulary=list(vocab), mask_token=None, name='lookup')
chars_from_ids = StringLookup(vocabulary=ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary(), invert=True, mask_token=None)
all_ids = ids_from_chars(tf.strings.unicode_split(text, "UTF-8"))
ids_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_ids)

sequence_length = 100
examples_per_epoch = len(text)//(sequence_length+1)

sequences = ids_dataset.batch(sequence_length+1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = sequences.map(split_input_target)

dataset = (
  dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
  .batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
  .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIMENSION, batch_input_shape=[BATCH_SIZE, None]))
model.add(SimpleRNN(RNN_UNITS, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size,))

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
  filepath=CHECKPOINT_PREFIX,
  save_weights_only=False,
  save_best_only=False,
  verbose=1 
)

loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True)
model.summary()
model.fit(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
model.save("./model/")

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./model/")
next_char = tf.constant(["After "])
result = []

for n in range(256): 
  next_char = generate_char(next_char)
  result.append(next_char)

print(tf.strings.join(result)[0].numpy().decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code; when facing a similar problem with the TF text prediction tutorial, UNK can be avoided using adding one element to the vocabulary size to hold the UNK:

```
vocab_size = len(vocab) + 1
```